# Directives Instances are sharing Ajax Results, but I dont want them to

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, angularjs

I added two instances of a directive but then when they execute upon loading the ajax request inside what only registers is ONE ajax request but when read in the console there are two execution of console.log but the results are the same but the backend is suppose to provide random results.

Im expecting that there is suppose to be 2 ajax requests with very unlikely chance of ever having the same result but it doesnt happen, they share results.

Here is the Directive:

app.directive('humanize',function($http)
{

```
return {
    restrict:"EA",
    template:'template stuff',
    replace: true,
    transclude: 'element',
    scope:{
        key:"=",
        activate:"=",
        theme:"@"
    },
    link:function (scope, elem, attrs) { 
        scope.question="";
        scope.placeholder="";
        scope.answer="";
        scope.key="";            
                    var temp_key;
        $http({ url:stage.ajax_url,method: "GET",params: {'action':'do_ajax','fn':'human'}}).success(function(data) {
            scope.question=data.question;
            scope.placeholder=data.placeholder;
            temp_key=data.key;  
            console.log(temp_key);  
        });


    }
}
```

});

What am I doing wrong here? I need multiple instances of the directive to have different ajax results...

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the angular directives it just that CHROME was seeing the request as the same therefore not executing it... and just binding the same data to every ajax request...